# Write extra </div> tag without Blogger auto-correcting it

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I found a code for a [Top Commentators Blogger](http://www.sneeit.com/2014/05/top-commentators-widget-for-blogger.html) widget online, and it's perfect for my needs. The problem is, it seems the code lacks a `</div>` tag. This way, it messes up the code of everything below it on my Blogger (following widgets gets nested inside it, for eg.).

The widget's code is written in encrypted js (?), so I can't change it. So I decided to add the missing `</div>` tag manually, on the widget content. But Blogger magical autocorrection of HTML thinks it's just some extra wrong code and erases it. I've tried writing it with js and `innerHTML` too, but Blogger still erases it.

Any suggestions on how to add this `</div>` without it getting removed?

The widget can be seen live (and working wrongly, nesting the Archive inside it) at the bottom of my page: [www.comoeurealmente.com](http://www.comoeurealmente.com)

Comment: Firstly, please add screenshot of non working site, so once the issue is resolved, people can still see if the answer it can help them. Now, about your question..:)

Comment: maybe add another opening <div> at beginning or wherever applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like the `</div>` tag is missing to me.  It seems that your css is indenting the archive with `.footer` and `.widget` having a padding of 25px.  change that padding to 0px and the page displays correctly.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not the problem. It's like this because the archive widget is nested inside the Top Commentators widget.
But I wonder if Blogger actually "forgot" to erase my `/div` written with js when you rendered the page, and everything seemed fine because of it?

Comment: Maybe, although that would be very strange for it to happen/not happen randomly.  I hope someone else is smarter with how blogger works than I am for you!